# changing state buttons in tkinter

Tags: tkinter

This is my base code. Im using Python 3.4. Button 1 active, Button 2 not active. Button 1 when clicked doing his function and should change state of both buttons - B1 to not active, B2 to active.

And back. B2 active and B1 not, when B2 clicked do function and change buttons state to start of program.

Can You tell me how do this?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

b1 = Button(root, text='button 1', bg='black',
            fg='green').pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1, padx=5, pady=5)

b2 = Button(root, text='button 2', bg='black',
            fg='red', state='disabled').pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1, padx=5, pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: BTW: `var = Widget().pack()` convert to `var = Widget()` and `var.pack()`

Comment: use `Button( ... , command=function_name_without_() )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to change `var = Widget().pack()` into

```
var = Widget()
var.pack()
```

to get access to widget.

And then you can use `command=` to assign function to button.

```
import tkinter as tk

def change_1():
    b1['state'] = tk.DISABLED
    b2['state'] = tk.NORMAL

def change_2():
    b1['state'] = tk.NORMAL
    b2['state'] = tk.DISABLED

root = tk.Tk()

b1 = tk.Button(root, text='Button 1', command=change_1)
b1.pack()

b2 = tk.Button(root, text='Button 2', command=change_2, state=tk.DISABLED)
b2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I have one more question: can button do two commands at the same time right after one click? Both buttons from my app have functions allready. They do command=doSomething, and what is wrote here uses command

Comment: run `change_1` inside your `doSomething` function ?

Comment: or run your `doSomething` function inside `change_1`

Comment: ok, it was stupid question. I have figured out that i need to be more relaxed - if not, i'm making stupid mistakes

Comment: it wasn't so stupid question :) you can assign second function using `bind('<Button-1>', function)` but it will be executed even when button is disabled. http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm